# How to use CONTAINS() and LOWER() together in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am developing a stored proc in SQL Server 2012

In some part I would like to determine the condition if "NAME" contains sub-string @pattern, **Case Insesitive-ly**

**@pattern is a string with lower case letters only**

Somehow I've tried

`where CONTAINS(NAME, @pattern)` is fine

but when I add LOWER()

`where CONTAINS(LOWER(NAME), @pattern)`

It gives me syntax error.

I am new to T-SQL, can anyone help me out?

1. Why is it syntax error, and how to solve it?
2. Is there any better way to do exact the same task?

Thanks!

Comment: does your table full-text indexed?

Answer (score 2):

if your table not full-text indexed then `CONTAINS` will not work

another variants to solve your issue below:

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE ( SomeText VARCHAR(40) )
INSERT  INTO @table
VALUES  ( 'abcdfh' ),
        ( 'ghijkl' ),
        ( 'mnopq' );

DECLARE @pattern AS VARCHAR(10) 
SET @pattern = '%abc%'

--variant using like
SELECT  T.sometext
FROM    @table AS T
WHERE   T.SomeText LIKE @pattern

--variant using PATINDEX
SELECT  sometext
FROM    @table AS T
WHERE   PATINDEX(@pattern, T.SomeText) > 0

--variant using CHARINDEX, but it can't be used with '%' and '[ ]',
--just to find first char position of the searched word in text as below
SET @pattern = 'abc'
SELECT  sometext
FROM    @table AS T
WHERE   CHARINDEX(@pattern, T.SomeText) > 0
```

Comment: turns out I have solved the problem using LIKE similar to what you suggested...and I do not know what is "full-text indexed", thanks anyway, +1

Comment: @shole: Why did you use CONTAINS then? It's hardly advisable to use something you know little about. CONTAINS has to do with full-text search, and a full-text index is a related concept.

Comment: @Vasily: `PATINDEX('%[abc]%', source)` (or `source LIKE '%[abc]%'`) and `CHARINDEX('abc', source)` are very different things, though. There's no simple equivalent of the former using CHARINDEX.

Comment: I did not know it was related, how i found this function is because c# has a similar function doing similar task

Comment: @shole: I see. I was under the impression that CONTAINS was one of the less often used features of T-SQL, but maybe the situation will change thanks to C#. :)

Comment: @AndriyM yes sure, but I already wrote that `charindex` can't be used similar with `like` and `@pattern` also has been updated, take a look in comment above the code

Comment: Yes, but I think it would make more sense if you made your examples equivalent and used `%abc%` instead of `%[abc]%` for the first two methods. (Just my opinion. Maybe others don't see a problem here, I don't know.)

Comment: @AndriyM post has been updated for those who will face with such case